# Nature of components of two unpolarized lasers with the same characteristics

Tags: optics

From what I understand, unpolarized laser light is composed of two orthogonal components with different frequencies. Thus, since there is not definite phase relationship between the components, the light becomes randomly polarized. Now if you were two procure two of the same type of unpolarized laser sources (by same type I mean the same model from the same company) would you find that the two lasers would have orthogonal components with the same characteristics? For example, would the vertical component one laser be of the same frequency as the vertical component of the other laser, and would the horizontal component of one laser be of the same frequency as the horizontal component of the other laser?

Comment: the phase relationship or lack of it between two signals of different frequencies has nothing to do with their respective polarization

Comment: I had posted an answer, but I hadn't read the OP carefully enough, and I answered a question not asked.  I deleted my answer, and will try to give a better answer.